# reading querysting from page url inside controller action result?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC controller I need to read GUID which is part of URL. Below is my URL:

```
http://localhost:56445/Dir1/SubDir1/f3164d1b-38bf-4811-9327-a24200c7614b
```

Or it can be like:

```
http://localhost:56445/Dir1/f3164d1b-38bf-4811-9327-a24200c7614b
```

I am aware of Request.UrlRefferal but I want to avoid parsing. Is there any way I can read it please

Answer (score 2):

```
var guid =urlString.Split('/').Last()
```

OR

```
Uri uri = new Uri(urlString);
string guid = uri.Segments.Last();
```

if you want to use `Request.UrlReferrer` then

```
string guid = Request.UrlReferrer.Segments.Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC, Action method for that view is already capable of accepting the

```
public ResultAction Detail(string guid){
  //use guid here.
}
```